# A line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> If $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=\rho^{-1}\mathbf{e}_{\phi}$ in cylindrical polars, find:
>
> $$\int_{C}\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$
>
> where $C$ is the circle $z=0,\rho=1,\;0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$. Also find $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}$

My try:

$$\int_{C}\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_C (\rho^{-1}\mathbf{e}_{\phi})\cdot (\mathbf{e}_{\rho}d\rho+\rho\mathbf{e}_{\phi}d\phi+\mathbf{e}_{z}dz)=\int_C \mathrm{d}\phi=2\pi$$

This seems way too easy. Is it wrong? For the second part I get $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=-\rho^{-3}\mathbf{e}_z$ but a friend of mine says it should be $0$...

Comment: What does $e_\phi$ denote?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Basis vector for $\phi$ in cylindrical polars ($\mathbf{e}_{\phi}=\boldsymbol{\hat \phi}$)

Comment: @WPL Your calculation $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=-\rho^{-3}$ is clearly wrong, because the LHS is a vector field and the RHS is a scalar field.

Comment: @DavidH It's fixed

Comment: @WPL This problem is trying to get you to notice that something fishy is going on here. Your calculation of the line integral $\int_{C}\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=2\pi$ is correct. What if you instead tried to calculate the value of the line integral via Stokes' Theorem? Well, $\int_{C}\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_S(\nabla\times B)\cdot d\mathbf{a}$. But wait! The curl of $B$ is zero, so the integral must also be zero. Hence, $2\pi=0$???

Comment: @DavidH Oh I see. Is this because the unit disc without the origin is not a simply connected domain?

Comment: @WPL No, that's not it. Have you ever heard of Dirac delta functions?

Comment: @DavidH Yes. Are you saying $\int_S \nabla\times \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a}$ blows up at the origin if $S$ includes the origin but is $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @WPL that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses part 2 which asks for the curl of $\mathbf B$. Your friend is correct that the curl is identically zero.

The components of the curl of a vector field $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{e}_{\rho}B_{\rho}+\mathbf{e}_{\phi}B_{\phi}+\mathbf{e}_{z}B_{z}$ in cylindrical coordinates are:

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{e}_{\rho}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial\phi}-\frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial z}\right) + \mathbf{e}_{\phi}\left(\frac{\partial B_{\rho}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial \rho}\right) + \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho B_{\phi}\right)-\frac{\partial B_{\rho}}{\partial \phi}\right)$$

For the function $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=B_{\phi}(\rho)\mathbf{e}_{\phi}=\rho^{-1}\mathbf{e}_{\phi}$, the $\rho$ and $z$ components are zero: $B_{\rho}=B_z=0$. And since the $\phi$ component $B_{\phi}=\rho^{-1}$ is independent of $\phi$ and $z$, $\frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial z}=0$. Thus, the formula for the curl reduces to:

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{e}_{\rho}\left(-\frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial z}\right) + \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho B_{\phi}\right)\right) \\
 = \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho B_{\phi}\right)\right)\\
 = \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\rho \rho^{-1}\right)\right) = \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(1\right)\right) = \mathbf{e}_{z}\frac{1}{\rho}\left(0\right) = \mathbf0.$$

Comment: I missed factor of $\rho$... Thank you for this. Does this not imply $\mathbf{B}=\nabla f$ for some $f$ and hence the integral is path independent (and therefore $0$ in this case)?

Comment: @WPL Indeed it does. Try $f=\phi$.